# z-index inside float without overflow into sibling nodes

Tags: html, css

**Consider the following DIV structure:**

```
<style>
#content{float:left;width:100%;}
#overlay{position:absolute;z-index:100;}
</style>

<body>
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="overlayBox">
        <div id="overlay">
            I want to overlay #content. 
            If my height is greater than
            #content, I don't want to 
            spill onto other elements. 
            I want to push them away.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">content</div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</body>
```

**In the example I want to:**

Push `#header` and `#footer` away if `#overlay` becomes greater height than `#content`

*Even if this DIV structure is completely wrong, it's only being used to illustrate the need.*

---

This is a good example of the problem I am having:
http://jsfiddle.net/Udqkc/

Comment: Your markup seems fine, what you actually need?

Comment: @Mr.Alien This doesn't work. This is just concept. Can you provide quick solution that does what I am trying to achieve via jsfiddle or something?

Comment: I did made a fiddle out of your provided markup, it does push away the header and footer

Comment: @Mr.Alien http://jsfiddle.net/Udqkc/ this seems to overlap the footer, what I need is for the footer to be pushed away, even if the overlay height is greater than the content height.

Comment: You can't do that with css as you are using `position: absolute;`

Comment: @Mr.Alien How do I achieve an overlay with the desired effect?

Comment: why you can't use it like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Udqkc/8/

Comment: @Mr.Alien `#overlay` needs to give the illusion of being on top of `#content`

Comment: If you want to push your content down, there will be no illusion as such :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien not trying to push the `#content` down. Im trying to overlay the `#content`. The problem is pushing the `#footer` down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, moved `#content` into `#overlayBox`:

```
    <div id="overlayBox">
        <div id="overlay">
            I want to overlay #content. 
            If my height is greater than
            #content, I don't want to <br />
            spill onto other elements. <br />
            I want to push them away.
        </div>
        <div id="content">content</div>
    </div>
```

Slightly changed CSS:

```
#overlay {float:left;}
#overlayBox {overflow:hidden;}
#content {position:absolute;}​
```

Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/nKwQF/14/

Hope this helped, cos I'm not sure if you're able to move `#content`

Comment: this is exactly what i need except for one thing. is there any way you can modify this to give the same effect but keeping `#content` as a float?

Comment: really, now that i think about it... if `#content` was bigger than `#overlay`, i would still want the overlay to be at least equal height of content. think background modal.

Comment: Well, maybe there is a way to do this with CSS, but I have no ideas right now, and I'm not sure if I will. But, if you can use some JS, this will be quite simple - http://jsfiddle.net/68PbU/14/ Even without changing initial markup and styles. (jQuery used, but it can be done without it, just more code)

Comment: yea i ended up havng to use javascript to dynamically resize. if you find a CSS version of this that would be great.